# Check if same username exists in sql server management..... if so dont add the username

Tags: c#, winforms

It is showing me 2 errors.. please help .....required for my project work

The error showing in both cases is as follows:-

> Error 1   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter' does not contain a
>   definition for 'loginregistration' and no extension method
>   'loginregistration' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter' could be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {

            if (txtUsername.Text == "" || txtEmail.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter all Details");
            }
            else
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from loginregistration WHERE username='" + txtUsername.Text + "'", con);

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds);
                int i = da.loginregistration[0].Rows.Count;//.........(ERROR HERE)
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Username Already Exists");
                    da.Clear();//............(ERROR HERE)
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd1 = con.CreateCommand();
                        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                        cmd1.CommandText = "insert into loginregistration(username,FirstName,LastName,Email,Address,Contact_No) VALUES('" + txtUsername.Text + "','" + txtFirstName.Text + "','" + txtLastName.Text + "','" + txtEmail.Text + "','" + txtAddress.Text + "','" + txtContact.Text + "')";
                        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        con.Close();
                        disp_data();
                        MessageBox.Show("Inserted Successfully");
                        txtUsername.Text = txtFirstName.Text = txtLastName.Text = txtEmail.Text = txtContact.Text = txtAddress.Text = "";
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("ex.Message");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should use a unique constraint on your database table's username field to prevent duplicates and then check for errors after executing the query.  This will allow for large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Let's extract a method for checking user's existence. We don't need to load all the data into a `DataTable` with a help of `SqlDataAdapter`; one query will be enough:

```
private bool UserExists(string userName) {
  if (null == userName)
    return false;

  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Connection_String_Here")) {
    conn.Open();

    // Keep query readable
    // Make query parametrized
    string sql =
      @"select 1 
          from LoginRegistration
         where UserName = @prmUserName";

    // Do not share the single connection, but create a new one
    using (SqlCommand q = new SqlCommand(sql, conn)) {
      q.Parameters.Add("@prmUserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userName;

      // If we can read at least one record
      using (var reader = q.ExecuteReader()) {
        // we can be sure the user exists
        return reader.Read();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, let's use our method:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUsername.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtEmail.Text))
  MessageBox.Show("Please enter all Details");
else {
  if (UserExists(txtUsername.Text)) 
    MessageBox.Show("Username Already Exists");
  else {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use dataset

```
DataSet loginregistration = new DataSet(); 
da.Fill(loginregistration ,"loginregistration ");
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix your existing code:

```
 int i = da.loginregistration[0].Rows.Count;
```

should be

```
 int i = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
```

That said you should pay attention to the answer Dmitry gave and parameterise your SQL. Your current method is wide open to SQL Injection.